# Should I put comma between two successive equations?

Tags: math-mode, equations, formatting, thesis

I am writing my thesis and I am confused about where to put commas or not. I am aware that equations follow the same grammatical rules as text. I am giving a simple example below where I am defining two different entities 'a' and 'b'. Should there be a comma after the first equation, a period, or no punctuation at all? I personally think that the second representation below is correct, but I am not sure. Kindly guide me about it. Thank you.

*Option 1*:

```
Let us define two operators a and b as
a = b+c,
d= e+f.
```

*Option 2*:

```
Let us define two operators a and b as
a = b+c
d= e+f.
```

*Option 3*:

```
Let us define two operators a and b as
a = b+c.
d= e+f.
```

Comment: How about using the word `and` between the two equations?

Comment: @Mico Yes, that is a good choice, but similar equations appear in my thesis repeatedly and I think it would be hectic to use the word 'and' again and again. :)

Comment: An equation is an individual unit.  You have "a and b".  That's what you should have for their equations: "a=... and b=...".  If you have "a, b, and c", then you would have "a=..., b=..., and c=...".  You'll have to specify how using "and" would become hectic if it happens repeatedly.

Comment: @Teepeemm Then I guess using 'and' is the better choice here.

Comment: Not really a TeX issue but I'd use either "and" as Mico suggested, or a comma (your first version). The third solution is surely wrong.

Comment: Recommended reading, [A Guide to Writing Mathematics](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~amenta/w10/writingman.pdf). Above any rule: be consistent, whatever you choose, do it always. It is a style dependent situation, I'd go with Options 1 and 2, but it really depends on what kind of math you are typing, I'd go with `1` in a sequence of steps (showing a resolution without commenting) and `2` when showing two separated but related equations. I'd avoid Option 3 since periods basic ends the sentence, there is no sense using it. I avoid `and`s because in my language I should use `e` formatted as text.

Comment: Related: [Oxford Comma](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/412)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider the equations to be part of the sentence, so some semblance of normal grammatical rules apply. Pick a style you (and your supervisor(s)) are happy with and apply it consistently.

Consider these snippets:

[image: Two separate equations separated by text]

and

[image: Multiple equations together]

Comment: I have seen in some books where they define different equations, but don't put commas in between. I was wondering if that is a grammatical error or just a choice of style?

Comment: I've just checked through a bunch of books on my desk and they all conform to the above style (and they're all different publishers, but all in the sameish, physics/crystallography field). It my just be a stylistic choice.

Comment: Okay thank you:)

Answer (score 5):

What you are showing is a list of things so punctuate as a list. Two items use "and" or "or": "You can have yellow or red." Three or more items use commas between the first items and "and" or "or" before the last: "You can have yellow, green or blue."

Comment: Don't forget the possibility of the Oxford comma: "You can have yellow, green, or blue." I know it is somewhat controversial, but some times it is necessary: "I was out last night with the strippers, my boss and my wife." is ambiguous.

Comment: @Arthur you can pry my Oxford comma from my cold, dead hands.

Comment: @masher Don't you mean "my cold, dead, hands"? ;)

Comment: I'm a Cambridge man, myself.

Answer (score 5):

You should probably use something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Let us define two operators $a$ and $d$ as
\begin{align}
  a &= b+c\\
\shortintertext{and}
  d &= e+f\quad.
\end{align}

or

Let us define two operators $a$ and $d$ as
\begin{align*}
  a &= b+c && \text{and} & d &= e+f\quad.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't you think the `\quad` before the period give a too large space?

Comment: You can play with smaller spaces or none, but the period is going to be nearly invisible anyway.  I usually end such sentences with "where $b>0$." or something similar.

Comment: @JohnKormylo This is a good way to put 'and' between equations. Thanks for making me familiar with the 'shortintertext' command. :)

Answer (score 3):

As we already have a nice answer regarding to when use commas (@masher's answer), let me add for completeness the example from [A Guide to Writing Mathematics](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Eamenta/w10/writingman.pdf) where commas should be avoided. The example shows a sequence of steps during a resolution, a proof or any other sequence of operations in which the author is not commenting or explaining between them. Equation number is not mandatory, inserting it or not is another discussion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
The resolution is presented as follows:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    3^{2x} - 2 (3^x)      & = -1 \\
    (3^x)^2 - 2 (3^x) + 1 & = 0  \\
    (3^x - 1)^2           & = 0  \\
    3^x                   & = 1  \\
    x                     & = 0.
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
Notice there were no commas between steps.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The period after `0` makes clear we ended the sequence of steps. Sometimes people don't add it, which kind of breaks the reading flow, but it is understandable when no equation has periods, this case is more just a quick resolutions guide style than an explanatory article or book style. The period could be a comma, depending on context around it, in this case `notice` would have `n` instead of `N` following the standard rules of the language.

Comment: I agree with this. In this case, the equations all belong together, and aren't their own separate thing.

Comment: @FHZ Good point! Thanks!